# OpenCL coalesced

Tags: c, opencl

I was working with different kernel recently, and I noticed that I have inefficient read/write (In my opinion at least).

I read about coalesced memory access, I think I get it, but I don't know what wrong. So I went for a simple test :

```
__kernel void TestCoalesced(__global float* data) {
    data[get_global_id(0)] = 200.0f; 
}
```

I enqueue the kernel as follow :

```
  m_err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(m_queue, m_kernel, 1, NULL, (size_t)(6220800), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Which is an example call similar to an image I previously used (1920*1080*3 = 6220800 = about 6mb).

So that kernel is just writing at position of the work-item in the array. This should not be faster ? It's take about 1.06ms and when I look in CodeXL, the cache hit % is at 0.

[image]

Is there anything I do wrong ? I have a AMD Radeon R7 200 series with 2Go.

**EDIT**:

Based on comment below, my question could change to :

Is there any tools or profiler to know if my data access is coalesced ? Because I feel like my kernel are running slow, for such simple task.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I feel like this writing is slow and CodeXL saying that my "writing" cache hit % is 0%. Which looks like I'm never using the cache of the coalesced memory access.

Comment: You are not using cache. What you wrote is just streaming 6.2MB of data. But, for example, running a simple nearest-neighbor-search algorithm  can do 40% cache hit. Because cache is useful when a data is accessed multiple times, especially by multiple workitems.

Comment: So is it normal to have a 1ms for that kind of code ? It's seems a bit much to me, just for a data "transfer" when everything lie on the GPU already. Because I tried different functions before (mostly color conversion, RGB to LAB, RGB to HSV, etc.) and those are taking something like ~5ms and they have a cache hit % of ~30%. So I was wondering if it was coalesced or not. And what was wrong. Because same color conversion on CPU without OpenCL is about 4-5ms already. So with image transfer to device + computing, its much longer than I expect.

Comment: So cache hit % doesn't mean my data access is not coalesced (my miss-interpretation of CodeXL tools I think).

Comment: I updated my question. Because I feel like my kernel are slow. And first, I though it was due to cache hit (though it meant coalesced), but those are not related so now, I want to know what wrong with my code.

Comment: Submitting a kernel and waiting for it to complete has a certain overhead associated with it, so microbenchmarking with a kernel that doesn't do anything useful isn't particularly informative.

Comment: `data[get_global_id(0)] = 200.0f; ` doesn't even test memory performance. Main bottleneck could be number of workitems, kernel launch overhead and even latency of compiling/just-in-time-optimizing the kernel . Try enqueueing 100 kernels before synchronizing to elliminate kernel launch overhead from benchmarking. You can still do coalesced access by lesser number of workitems to elliminate workitem launching overhead. Also run it at least 100 times and get average timings to elliminate spikes and driver optimizations.

Comment: I will give it a test with my original function which is not that code sample for the purpose of the question and see what going on.

Comment: I gave a shot, based on a test, my kernel really take between 6.19 to 6.78ms with an average of 6.33ms. And if I remove my computing part (so only reading and writing => `output[get_global_id(0)] = intput[get_global_id(0)];` This is between 2.01 to 2.70ms, for average of 2.52ms. My image are 1920x1080x3 (6.2mb)* channels and I read them as Float* (24mb). Is ~1.25ms for a read + ~1.25ms for a write is logic, I feel like this could be much faster no ?

Comment: @Vuwox 24MB data generated and copied in 2.5 ms is nearly 10 GB/s. If you are working on video-ram(not using main-memory-mapped buffer) then it looks slow. If it is 1.25ms then it is 20 GB/s. Whats your GPU exactly? R7-240 or R7-250?

Comment: R7-200. I create a buffer on the device as follow : `clCreateBuffer(m_context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, bufferSize, NULL, &m_err);`, which is suppose to create a buffer aligned on the device directly. It's not associated with any memory block on the host. I use the `clEnqueueReadBuffer` to read from that cl_mem afterward. The output[idx] = input[idx] take 2.5ms (I divided as read/write this is why I supposed 1.25ms).

Comment: After few search and help of GPUz, I got a R7-240 Low Profile (R7240-2GD3-L).

Comment: @Vuwox Then I suggest you to try a write-only buffer, do the assignment by float2 instead of float and have at least 100MB data. I guess each should give %10 more writing performance on top of each other. There is also possibility of marketting 30GB/s could be actually sum of write+read bandwidths or simply only achieved with using multiple command queues concurrently. Re-test with GPU overclock also. If it gets faster then its still core dependent(but shouldn't be).

Comment: For the purpose on the example, a write-only could do it. But I need a read/write buffer in my main algorithm (could re-visit this in case that I see a huge performance difference in-between W and RW). But I don't understand what you mean by float2 assigment ? Change float* to float2* and do double assignment ? if so, reduce the global size from CPU enqueue right ? And why at least 100mb of data ? What the disavantage of being under ? I don't understand everything. But thanks a lot for all those answer! I will do the Write only testing to see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158986/discussion-between-huseyin-tugrul-buyukisik-and-vuwox).

Comment: I would suggest going through http://developer.amd.com/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/opencl-optimization-guide/ as @huseyintugrulbuyukisik said you should try optimization after you get the flow right. I saw you explanation about you application in another questio, I still don't understand the one large memory allocation you are trying to do. There might be a different way to solve the issue. You should also try playing with local work group sizes which alters memory access patterns, you might see some unexpected gains. https://github.com/CNugteren/CLTune might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I have been working a bit more on my flow and I get decent result now. I changed few things and everything work good. I put the optimization on the side and try to go ahead more on pipeline and finish to function and make them work. At least, it's going well. I have so many function to re-code that I have tons of time to learn differents tricks and come back for future optimization. I appreciate the help kanna. And thanks for that tool, I might give it a shot.